# Using selenium in python to extract values in this form

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

How can I extract the value from a html file in this form using selenium:

```
<body>
   <div class="some stuff">
      <span class="some other stuff">the number wanted</span>
   </div>
</body>
```

I tried using the get_attribute function on the element but that can only return the class.

Code so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("website")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath to wherever')
print(elem.get_attribute("value")) #tried originally
driver.close()
```

Also important to note that the website must be signed in the particular website I was trying wouldnt work for most people.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can we see your code so far?

Comment: added code now, with generalised bits

Comment: I've added an answer, if it doesn't work let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is within the < span >, you can use .text to get the inner text of the element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("website")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath to wherever')
print(elem.text) #Get the inner text of elem
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Other approach you can use `.get_attribute("innerHTML")`, it can be used to get text inside the `span` tag.

While `.get_attribute ("value")` can be used for other component type such as `input`